# error when attempting to seed pivot table using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-seeding

I have just created a many-to-many relationship between the models Project and Features using Laravel however I receive the following error when attempting to run the seed script.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'table.feature_projects' doesn't exist
```

The table in use is named features_project which is the default name given.

Inserting the seed data manually does return the relational data to the view as expected.

**SEED**

```
class FeaturesProjectTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

public function run()
{
    $features_project = new \App\FeatureProject ([
        'project_id' => '1',
        'features_id' => '1'
    ]);
    $features_project->save();
}
}
```

**Project**

```
<?php 
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Project extends Model {
        
        public function features() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Features')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Features**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Features extends Model
{
    public function projects() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
{

public function getProject($id)
{
    $project = Project::where('id', $id)->get();
    return view('other.project', ['project' => $project]);
}

}
```

**ROUTE**

```
Route::get('project/{id}', [
'uses' => 'ProjectController@getProject',
'as' => 'other.project'
]);
```

**VIEWS**

```
@foreach($project->features as $feature)
 <dd class="col-sm-8">{{ $feature->name }}</dd>
@endforeach
```

Comment: add your seeder class

Comment: added seed class

Answer (score 2):

Firstly some misunderstanding in naming, your table name should be `feature_project`, in many to many relationships the models are in alphabetical order. Secondly models are not plural, so your `Features.php` model should be named `Feature.php`. Which will resolve in `Laravel` using the table `feature_project` for the pivot and `features` for the model.

For your own sake, learn how Laravel name models and tables, else relationships are gonna be tricky. Which is described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

You should not create pivot models, this is handled by assigning features to projects or vice versa. Therefor your seeder should look something like this, it could be you should assign some attributes to the projects and features before it will work.

```
class FeaturesProjectTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        $features = factory(Feature::class)->create();

        $projects = factory(Project::class)->create();

        $projects->each(function (Project $project) {
            $project->features()->saveMany($features);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am new to Laravel yes working my way through the documentation today, The first many to many seed I created worked first time but this one is not working yet